# Proving existence of path graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

An individual is walking on a 1D horizontal line. There exists multiple Flashers on the line. A Flasher is a device that can instantly teleport an individual from one endpoint to another, on the same line. This path of teleportation can be visualized as an arc over the line.
Suppose the individual wants to walk eastward. Flashers are spread out arbitrarily on the line. Although path of teleportation can overlap, the endpoints cannot. So for example, a path from a1 to a2 can have an arc that overlaps with b1 to b2, but the endpoints cannot start/end at the same place. Here is a visual diagram: [image]

Depending on which endpoint the individual reaches, the individual can be transported eastward or westward (for example, if the individual somehow walked onto endpoint b2, they will be transported back to b1.

The question is, how can we prove that no matter how the Flashers are placed, the individual will always reach the destination t? I assume some knowledge of graph theory is required, but I am confused because this does not seem like a DAG

Comment: What's stopping somebody from just walking to the right, and any time a "flasher" sends them backwards, just riding the same flasher in reverse and then continuing forwards?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, turning this problem into a graph:

- Nodes: **S**, a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2, d1, d2, **t**
- Edges:

  - if it's an arc: **bidirectional** edge with **cost=0**
  - if it's a "natural" path (ex. S->a1 or a1 -> b1): **directed** edge with **cost=1**

Your example then turns into:

[image]

To follow the problem's rules we have to traverse the graph from S to t following always the edge with lowest cost available (excluding the edge just used to arrive to a node).

Turning these lines and Flashers into graphs will always result in a graph with an important property: **each node has exactly 2 directed edges (one coming and one going) and exactly 1 undirected edge.** (except S and t).

Now, the only way for t to not be reachable is if a cost=0 loop exists in the graph. Because of the property mentioned this is impossible.


In fact, every node in the graph will eventually be reached except for "parallel bridges" such as (d1, d2) covered by (c1, c2). These nodes (d1, d2) can be easily detected and removed as they are impossible to reach. If there is anything inside one of this bridges that doesn't "teleport" outside of the bridge you can remove it too.

Answer (score 1):

First notice:

- the line consists of a finite number of line segments between the flasher endpoints
- the path is an alternation between line segments (always eastward) and flashers (any direction)
- to not reach the destination, the path needs to be infinite, containing a cycle

Now the **key idea: for every used edge (line segment or flasher), there's exactly one edge that may precede it**.

- to use a line segment, the path must come via the flasher on its western end
- to use a flasher westward, the path must come via the line segment leading to its eastern endpoint
- to use a flasher eastward, the path must come via the line segment leading to its western endpoint

So, if there is a cycle in the graph (like d1>d2>c2>c1 in your sample), it's only reachable from edges that are part of the cycle; **there's no way to enter the cycle** when coming from the line start.

(Even if there is a flasher right at the start, there's no line segment that can be used to reach it again, so the start is never a part of a cycle)

Therefore, **any path from the start will not be infinite and will reach the destination**.